# How to make UiTableView with multiple columns using swift 3

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3, multiple-columns, xcode8

I want to make a UiTableView with the same effect as the Apple Music app, I think it's done with UiTableView, when you have more than one column on it.
Here are some screenshot from my iPhone (notice the new album right under the Explorar, the next column is featured playlists:
[image: New album column]

[image: Featured playlists column]

Comment: it would be nice to have a answer to start with Instead of downvotes.

Comment: `UICollectionView` might play part of your project.

Comment: thank you very much. 
I'll look that up.

Comment: Actually you could have a good use of this framework developed by Instagram team: https://github.com/Instagram/IGListKit

Comment: My main problem is that I'm drawing a graphic on a UiView on each collection cell, I did managed to draw different graphics on each cell, but the graphic value its going to be different when the user updates the current values, and I can't figure out how to refresh the UiView, since I can't attach more than one controller to a repeated element.

Comment: But you could choose different subclass of `UIView` or `UIViewController` based on cell's index or other information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not multiple column. Its `UIScrollView` inside the `UITableViewCell` using `isPagingEnabled` feature.

You can also use `UICollectionView` inside the `UITableViewCell`.

I encourage you to check out [Putting a UICollectionView in a UITableViewCell in Swift](https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/) tutorial which explain this. I am sure you can implement same effect using this `UIScrollView` inside cell.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks!
I'll check that out, appreciate it.
Is there a reason for my question getting so many downvotes?

Comment: I am pretty sure you would be able to achieve same effect using that tutorial. I have used that in one my project. I am not sure about down votes buddy. I hope this could solve your problem though.

Comment: Yes it did, I'm already reading that tutorial and trying to implement what I want from it.
Thank you very much!